# Loop an array, removing unique values, leaving only the duplicates

Tags: swift

I have an array

```
allIDs = ["1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4"]
```

And I made the contents unique by  using

```
sortedIDs = Array(Set(allIDs))
```

Now I want to remove the unique strings in the allIDs array so all that will remain are the duplicates.

```
for item in sortedIDs {
while allIDs.contains(item) {
    if let itemToRemoveIndex = allIDs.index(of: item) {
        allIDs.remove(at: itemToRemoveIndex)
        print(allIDs)
    }
}
```

}

This gives me an allIDs array that is empty. I am stumped how a for loop that should loop four times is looping six times and removing all the items.
Thanks.

Comment: @dtd That's not a duplicate. The OP already knows how to remove duplicates. The problem is with creating a final array that contains only the duplicates.

Comment: What's your expected result? `["2", "2", "4", "4"]` or `["2", "4"]`?

Comment: My bad. I'll delete my comment. But I might suggest editing the question title to reflect the actual question.

Comment: @dfd I agree the title is completely wrong. Go ahead, edit it.

Comment: @Hamish I don't get it. Is there any mention of the desired output—using an example?

Comment: @Honey:  The question does *not* mention the desired output – that's why Hamish is asking for it.

Comment: For array `["1", "1", "1", "2"]` what is your expected result?

Comment: The answer to *"I am stumped how a for loop that should loop four times is looping six times and removing all the items"* is: Use the **debugger,** or add **print statements** which show what happens in your code.

Comment: @Hamish I am expecting ["2" , "4"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your desired result is `["2", "4"]`; the array of duplicates that were removed from the original array to get the `sortedIDs` array.

Your problem is the `while` loop that is looping until all copies of item have been removed from `allIDs`.  If you simply perform 1 remove for each item in `sortedIDs`, you will get the result you want:

```
for item in sortedIDs {
    if let itemToRemoveIndex = allIDs.index(of: item) {
        allIDs.remove(at: itemToRemoveIndex)
        print(allIDs)
    }
}
```